# Is it OK to handle 2 languages using session variable?

Tags: php, session-variables

To handle two languages, I have done the following and I want to know if it is fine.

On all my pages, I have a two links in the menu :

```
<a href="language.php?l=2">English</a>
<a href="language.php?l=1">Français</a>
```

On language.php, i set a session variable a go back to the page :

```
if(isset($_GET['l']))
{
    $_SESSION['language']= GetLanguage($_GET['l']);
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
}
```

Then on each php page, every time I have a word, I don't hardcode the it but instead put a PHP variable that depends on the value of $_SESSION['language'].

Do you see a problem using this mechanism ?

Comment: don't use the referer. it's not trustworthy, and not always set. but otherwise there's nothing wrong with the general logic.

Comment: I would suggest to use explicit language like en or en_US instead of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well - if you are using sessions - this is in essence why you would use sessions. So no problem.